# iOS add image to window in right orientation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I am trying to add an image view to my application window which consists of a splitviewcontroller. The reason I am doing this is so that I can fade it out like a splash screen. The application is for iPad and only works in the landscape mode. The launch image is the same as the splash image so it is a seamless transition between the two, then I can manually fade out the splash. However I am having trouble adding the splash to the window's subview in the same orientation as the launch image so that the transition from the launchimage to the splash is seamless and cannot be noticed. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;
    UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape~ipad.png"];
    [splash rotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    [window addSubview:splash];
}

@interface UIView (Orientation)

- (void)rotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;

@end

@implementation UIView (Orientation)

- (void)rotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    CGFloat angle = 0.0;

    switch (orientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            angle = M_PI;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = - M_PI / 2.0f;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = M_PI / 2.0f;
            break;

        default: // As portrait
            angle = 0.0;
            break;
    }
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you use the method -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate? The fact to rotate your view is not correct for your problem

Comment: Alright, and it still is not matching up with the launch image.

Comment: Can you describe the transition between the launch image and your splaschscreen?

Comment: There is no transition. When the launch image goes away, as controlled by the application, next the viewer will see is the imageview added to the application window. It should match exactly to the launch image in terms of position and orientation and size.